# Issue with resolving domains on CentOS 6

Tags: networking, centos

I was having an issue with updating YUM and also issues with CURL. This led me to find issues with resolving:

```
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.209.238
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
Host google.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.209.238
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4007:80f::200e
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.209.238
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
Host google.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
root@server [~]# host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.209.238
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
Host google.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
root@server [~]# host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.209.238
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4007:80f::200e
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

resolv.conf:

```
root@server [~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ovh.net
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Yum error:

```
root@server [~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6: cl-mirror.ptisp.com
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'download.fedoraproject.org'"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a solution please?

Comment: Execute `yum clean all` and try `yum update` again.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives a "PYCURL ERROR 6"

Comment: Interesting side note: The reason there is "Host google.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)" replies every now and then in the logs above, while the issue is just dropped UDP packets (rate limited or not), one would not expect a reply of NXDOMAIN for an existing name, is because of the interaction between the timeouts and the "search" option in the resolf.conf See https://blog.cloudflare.com/debugging-war-story-the-mystery-of-nxdomain/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you made lots of traffic or DNS queries? Google Public DNS has [rate limiting](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/security#rate_limit) and this can be the case, but the limit is about 20 queries per second. I can imagine this if some bot try bruteforce attack on SSH for example, in this case SSH make reverse lookup for every single connection and this can hit the limit. 
Try to chceck logs for suspicious activity or use tcpdump to check traffic on port 53

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 port 53
```

Also you can use another resolver from service provider, which can be more permisive or deploy local resolver, for example [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/)

Comment: I would definitely go with the local resolver (possibly on a dedicated node/container) - all else aside, if you are hitting rate-limits in this way, it sounds like you would see performance gains by using a more local resolver.

Comment: Thanks both - this looks like the issue, heavy traffic hitting the DNS. Will check why the increased traffic as well as deploying a local resolver.